Binding context in ContentPresenter in .NET MAUI
I'm still new in .NET MAUI so I still have some problems with basic concepts and best practices. Currently I'm struggling a bit with ContentPresenter.
So I have a custom component (ContentView) with ControlTemplate that uses ContentPresenter. Let us name this CustomControl.xaml
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>

Obviously I'm using MVVM so when I want to use CustomControl in a view I do this:
<ContentPage>
    <local:CustomControl>
        <Button Text="Click me" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
    </local:CustomControl>
</ContentPage>

where DoSomethingCommand is defined in my view model.
And this works perfectly fine, awesome! But what if I want to use multiple ContentPresenters in my CustomControl? As far as I know, I should bind content of ContentPresenter like this:
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding MyContent}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>

Of course I've defined BindableProperty in my code-behind file. And now I'm using my CustomControl like this:
<ContentPage>
    <local:CustomControl>
        <local:CustomControl.MyContent>
            <Button Text="Click me" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
        </local:CustomControl.MyContent>
    </local:CustomControl>
</ContentPage>

And my button shows up exactly where it should, but... there is absolutely no effect when clicking on it :(
I searched for a solution and I found out that I can use it like that:
<Button Text="Click me" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:MyViewModel}}, Path=DoSomethingCommand}" />

And that indeed works, but it looks awful and I don't understand it at all :( Could anyone please help me understand why this simple binding to my command doesn't work? Maybe I can/should modify somehow my CustomControl?

Similar to this issue, [Bug] BindingContext default behavior, on nested controls.

You can see that you have created the child element MyContent in the parent element CustomCrntrol. Using the bacis binding cannot get the data from the child element. Because you bind the viewmodel to the parent element not the child element.
 <local:CustomControl>
        <local:CustomControl.MyContent>
            <Button Text="Click me" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
        </local:CustomControl.MyContent>
</local:CustomControl>

This is why you need to use the relative binding in the button. FindAncestor indicates the ancestor in the visual tree of the bound element. This mode should be bind to an ancestor control respesented by AncestorType property.
<Button Text="Click me" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:MyViewModel}}, Path=DoSomethingCommand}" />


Actually the view model is bound to ContentPage so CustomControl is already a child of an element that "owns" the VM. So CustomControl "inherits" the VM without any issues and MyContent doesn't. Sorry, but I still don't get it :(
BTW I've found this article: https://thewissen.io/create-a-kickass-banking-app-using-a-basepage-in-xamarin/ . This looks as a workaround for me, since I can get rid of ContentPresenters at all, but is it considered a good practice in .NET MAUI?

Yes, the Customcontrol owns the VM but the MyContent will not. You need to use the relative binding to bind the data to the button in the MyContent.
